# Where are the game save files in PC? Bluestacks (without opening bluestacks)

Tags: files, bluestacks

There's someone who already asked this question but the answer requires opening bluestacks.

The problem is my bluestacks is broken and unable to open. It says 'Bluestacks app runner has stopped running'.

So I want to copy my game's save file, (Plants vs Zombies 2) and reinstall a new Bluestacks. So how do I manually search for the save in my computer?

Answer (score 1):

You can find  it at `C:\ProgramData\Bluestacks\android\SDCard.vdi`
You must show hidden files and folder at folder options to access ProgramData folder.
And you need a .vdi reader to open SDCard.vdi.
I used PowerISO (download it from Google) to open .vdi file.
Then open .vdi using PowerISO and search for your game. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can find your files in this location:
**"C:\ProgramData\BlueStacks\UserData\SharedFolder"**.

For more details, [click here](https://web.archive.org/web/20151104214327/http://support.bluestacks.com/hc/en-us/articles/203081537-How-to-access-your-PC-System-files-from-BlueStacks-)